# Adjust space to the sides of highchart series

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column graph with no x values, and a single point in each series.

Is there an option for reducing the empty space between

1. the first column and the y-axis
2. the last column and the right side of the graph?

http://jsfiddle.net/9hzx06rt/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {type: 'column'},
        series: [
          {data: [29.9]},
          {data: [144.0]},
          {data: [144.0]},
          {data: [144.0]},
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        groupPadding: 0
    }
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding